# Python: Passing an if statement to plot columns containing only float in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
   a        b           c          d          e         f         g        \
```

0  2.689023  2.574812   86.125377  11.092565   4.939444  2.851453  1.754082
1  2.072062  2.142972  107.184461  45.948551   2.181561  3.030148  1.347777
2  2.122226  2.282065   84.648076   5.524413  12.444351  3.265505  1.487924
3  2.134716  2.059546   87.338169   2.102929   6.992658  3.124260  1.569247
4  1.394049  1.588723   52.834432   3.743313   8.523079  2.710473  1.147418

```
   h         i          j          k          l         m           n      \
```

0  1.464062  63.088607  1.920668   85.786448  37.789046  23.080176  47.276513
1  1.026195  66.002393  1.297645  103.159307  19.147647  38.081938  91.625779
2  1.544903  63.542854  1.502209   90.655852  30.597791  33.488811  46.330959
3  1.464062  99.193164  1.910971  213.842295  36.663162  20.407577  46.259227
4  1.232436  61.228213  1.542646   71.922704  28.493704   8.649692  34.185022

```
  o          p       Time    Dose
```

0  1.505346  0.786096  2 hours  5mg/kg
1  2.249856  0.536542  2 hours  5mg/kg
2  5.700618  0.307784  2 hours  5mg/kg
3  3.583611  0.058229  2 hours  5mg/kg
4  2.170392  0.411765  2 hours  5mg/kg

What I am trying to do is to have individual plots for all the measured variables with Time on the x-axis and grouped by dose. Something like this:

[Basic_lineplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbqKm.png)

I can achieve this by using this command by passing each variable name one by one as y-value:

```
sns.factorplot(x="Time", y="a", hue="Dose", data=df2, kind="point")
```

However, since this becomes tedious, I wish to write a for loop that will plot only the columns having numeric values and exclude the columns 'Time' and 'Dose'. The code I am trying to use is this:

```
for i in df2:
    if df2.dtypes == float:
        lineplot = sns.factorplot(x="Time", y=i, hue="Dose", data=df2,
                   size=6, kind="point", capsize=.2, palette="dark", 
                   legend_out=False)
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), 
a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One thought: I would remove the units from the time and dose column and convert the values to floats

Comment: Yeah I tried doing that. But although it fixes this problem, it creates new ones when I take the same dataset for further analysis like structural equation modelling.

Comment: Depending on the size of your data, you could create two new columns without the strings and use them for calculations. Later on, you can use the string columns for your modelling

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to compare series to a single value in this particular line:

```
if df2.dtypes == float:
```

Trying writing this as:

```
if df2[i].dtypes == float:
```

Comment: Yes I did! Thanks once again.